# Add-in / App store validation regarding supporting versions

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

As PnP has separated the CSOM packages by 2013/16 and Online I am hoping that a single app is NOT required to support all these versions but I am not finding any store validation policy that addresses this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

One of the policy says

> Your add-in's packages must be correctly formatted and conform to the current manifest schema.

In the manifest schema you need to mention SharePoint Min and Max versions. So irrespective of what tool you used for dev (PnP/CSOM/REST..) the manifest needs to provide the minimum SharePoint version that is supported.

Comment: Does not seem to me to be clear. If CSOM nuget packages are separate by version then how could a min version of 13 satisfy requirements for 16 or online. If the "min" were removed then I could see how separate addins for each version were implied so I believe further clarification is necessary.

Comment: The point is as I plan to create an addin/app I need to figure out what all version my app is going to support.. based on that decision I will be using the appropriate API's isn't it? The validation policy will be used for approval of the app based on the definitions the app developer has provided.